# how to add special charecter in alias name in query written in visual studio 2010

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, special-characters, alias, space

the `%` is not working,

It is showing  The `SELECT` statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
string strCommand = "SELECT [Isonsite] AS Location, ROUND(((SUM([BilledFTE])/SUM([TotalFTE]))*100),2) AS BilledUtilization% FROM [" + getExcelSheetName + @"]  ";
```

Comment: waaaaait... .wait jsut one second...what's with the square brackets in there?

Comment: text inside square brackets are the column names in excel